# Definition and property of $X_{\bar{y}}$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In Hartshorne III.10.2, it defines $X_{\bar{y}}=X_y\otimes_{k(y)}k(y)^-$, where $k(y)^-$ is the algebraic closure of $k(y)$. It seems by the proof, it means it changes $X_{\bar{y}}$ from a scheme over field $k$ to a scheme over $k(y)^-$. But is this definition well-defined? Why does a topological space tensored with a field make sense?

Also by III.10.0.3, $X$ is smooth over $k$ if $X$ is regular of dimension $n$, if $X$ is irreducible and separated, then it's smooth iff it's non-singular and III.10.2 tells us $X_{\bar{y}}$ is regular. So does that mean when we consider the fiber at a non-closed point, if we want to see the fiber non-singular, we have to consider $X_{\bar{y}}$ instead of $X_y$?

In addition, how do we determine if $X_y\otimes_{k(y)}k(y)^-$ is irreducible and separated, does that suffice to check if $X_y$ is irreducible and separated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One frequent notational cheat that occurs in algebraic geometry is some sloppiness when dealing with base extensions over fields (though it appears that there's more than just the usual sloppiness here, and there's a typo too). The notion that Hartshorne is meaning to get at here is base-extending a scheme over a field to the algebraic closure of that field.

The scheme $X_y$ comes with a map $X_y\to \operatorname{Spec} k(y)$. There is also a map $\operatorname{Spec} \overline{k(y)}\to\operatorname{Spec} k(y)$ induced from the inclusion of $k(y)$ in to its algebraic closure $\overline{k(y)}$. $X_{\overline{y}}$ is supposed to be the fiber product of these two morphisms: $X_y\times_{\operatorname{Spec} k(y)}\operatorname{Spec} \overline{k(y)}$. The typo here is that Hartshorne has used $\otimes$ instead of $\times$, and the notational cheat is that frequently one finds in the literature the use of $\times_{k}$ instead of $\times_{\operatorname{Spec} k}$. (Writing $\times_k \overline{k}$ instead of $\times_k \operatorname{Spec}\overline{k}$ is less common, but I think I've still seen it a few times in the past.) This corrected definition removes any chance of questions of well-definedness if you understand fiber products of schemes.

For your second question, the answer is yes. The problem here is that there are actually two different definitions one might take of "non-singular": either we can ask for our scheme to be regular, or we can ask for our scheme to be geometrically regular (aka regular after base change to the algebraic closure). To really get at the geometry of what's going on, we would like to consider the second option, and there are times when the first option is not enough: consider the scheme $\operatorname{Spec} \Bbb F_p(t)[x,y]/(x^p+y^p=t)$ over the base $\operatorname{Spec} \Bbb F_p(t)$. This is regular, but not geometrically regular: over the field $\Bbb F_p(t^{1/p})$, every point is singular! So one does need to go to the algebraic closure to get the complete geometric picture.

As for your third question, separated schemes are stable under base extension (II.4.6), so it does suffice to check that $X_y$ is separated in order to show that $X_\overline{y}$ is separated. It does not suffice to check for irreducibility, though - schemes over a field which are irreducible after any base change by any field extension are called "geometrically irreducible". I would encourage you to try and come up with an example on your own of such a scheme before mousing over the below spoiler text containing an example:

> Consider $\Bbb R[x,y]/(x^2+y^2)$. This is irreducible because $x^2+y^2$ does not factor over $\Bbb R$, but it does factor over $\Bbb C$, and the base change to $\Bbb C$ is two lines meeting at a point (not irreducible!).

Comment: Although you said yes in your answer of my second question, but by your answer of my third question, does it imply given a smooth morphism between nonsingular varieties, at a non-closed point,  the $X_{\bar{y}}$ might not be a non-singular variety? Here a non-singular variety I mean an integral separated scheme of finite type over an algebraically closed field, s.t. the  stalk of the structure sheaf is a regular local ring.

Comment: By definition $X_{\overline{y}}$ is smooth, and by standard properties separated too. So the only interesting thing would be the integrality condition. It is not hard to construct counterexamples: consider something like $\operatorname{Spec}\Bbb Q[t,t^{-1},x]/(x^2-t) \to \operatorname{Spec} \Bbb Q[t,t^{-1}]$. The fiber over $(t-2)$ is a single point, but it's base change to the algebraic closure is two points. The correct thing to do here is to drop "integral" from your definition of "variety", and then your statement is correct.